# Does anyone know how to remedy fire-blight?

Tags: fruit-trees

Our neighborhood apple trees all have fireblight, I do see one tree with apples starting to appear, but the others do not have fruit.

Comment: Hi Susan, welcome to our site.  How do you know this is fireblight?  Did you have a Master Gardener or Arborist diagnose this?  Please send pictures.  Before any remedy or treatment we have to be sure of the problem.  Have you ever done a dormant oil/summer oil spray for your apples?  Close ups and the entire tree, please.